# Is there online mouse trainer for inverted aiming?

Tags: mouse

I know that there are some web based online mouse training pages. I looked today on a few but I use an *inverted Y* axis aiming.

Do you know any web pages supporting this style of aim training? I can't find anything. You think its even possible to simulate this in web browser?

Comment: It's probably easier to find software or a script that inverts your mouse, then use the regular training.

Comment: We are sorry but we cannot help you with requests for recommendations of software here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[spray.training](http://spray.training/) lets you check "Use inverted mouse controls" before starting.